Execute a cql script from neo4j shell
I am using neo4j-community-3.0.4 in linux and I am load to execute cql file in neo4j
a.cql

CREATE (this_s:Student { Name:'Sam', Title:'title', })

./bin/neo4j-shell -v -c < /root/a.cql

It gives output
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
648 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
neo4j-sh (?)$ //----------------------------------------------------------

But when I am trying to access the data using browser portal http://localhost:7474/browser/
I am not able to retrieve any data nor in left pane Database information I dont see the node getting created

neo4j 3.0.4 is 7 years old, and its documentation is no longer even available. Ideally, you should use cypher-shell in a recent version of neo4j.

I need to stick  this version only as compatibility issues

Try removing the extraneous "," after the Title property value. Cypher does not support dangling commas in a property map.
